# Covariance in non-standard inner product space

Tags: covariance

Can the classic definition of $Cov(X,Y) = E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$ be extended to include non-canonical inner products?

In my particular instance, I compute the inner product between matrices $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}$ as $\langle x, y \rangle_F = tr(x^Ty)$, the Frobenius inner product. We compute:
$$C(X,Y) := \int_{(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times d} \times \mathbb{R}^{n \times d}} \langle x, y\rangle_F \;d \mu(x,y)$$ for some probability measure $\mu$. Is it appropriate to term this (real-valued) result $C(X,Y)$ a ***covariance*** (assuming $E[X] = E[Y] = 0$)?

Edit: It's worth noting that for, say, $W, Z := vec(X), vec(Y)$ respectively, we could obtain a classic covariance matrix $\Sigma_{XY} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} = E[WZ^T]$, and then find $tr(\Sigma_{XY}) = C(X,Y)$ (by trace properties).